# Microsoft Edge PHP authentication not working without index.php in URL

Tags: php, basic-authentication, windows-10, http-status-code-401, microsoft-edge

At work we have a platform for a customer, requiring their employees to log in using HTTP Digest. To browse to the site, they type something like `theircompany.mycompany.com`. In Chrome/IE/FireFox, they can log in.

However, in Microsoft Edge, they can only log in if they type 
`theircompany.mycompany.com/index.php`. If they don't, the authentication screen keeps showing up, even after correctly entering their credential and the `network` section in the developer tools shows `401 Unauthorised`.

Does anyone know about this issue, how to fix it, or how to use a workaround next to actually appending index.php?

-EDIT- Below is the vhost file used for the site in question.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName theircomapny.mycompany.com

  LogLevel error
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/theircomapny.mycompany.com-access.log combined
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/theircomapny.mycompany.com-error.log
  DocumentRoot /var/www/theircompany

<Directory /var/www/theircompany>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$ [NC]
  RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]

</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName theircomapny.mycompany.com

  LogLevel error
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/theircomapny.mycompany.com-access.log combined
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/theircomapny.mycompany.com-error.log
  DocumentRoot /var/www/theircompany

<Directory /var/www/theircompany>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
# MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
```

-EDIT- I have just tried to reproduce the issue using a fresh MAMP installation and the sample code from example #2 located [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php)

Exactly the same happens, so I doubt it is any .htaccess issue.

Comment: Can you show your .htaccess and vhost?

Comment: I can, let me fetch them.

Comment: changing the url from `theircompany.mycompany.com` to `theircompany.mycompany.com/index.php` would be done in the `.htaccess`. So there is probably an error with your `.htaccess`.

Comment: Any idea how that could only happen in Microsoft Edge?

Comment: It's unlikely this is occurring because of an .htacess issue because I am having the exactly same issue on a Windows Server running PHP. Has anyone found a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 0):

This (failure to send an `Authorization: Digest` header on a re-request for the root path) is indeed a bug in Edge Legacy (reproing in the latest Windows 10 2004 builds), and a regression from Internet Explorer 11 which works properly.

It's fixed in the new Microsoft Edge (based on Chromium).